# save openvpn PKI passphrase

Tags: openvpn, pki

I'm using two servers.  VPN Server (A), and Client (B).

They are both using Ubuntu.
The VPN server was installed using PIVPN:

`curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash`

How do you save the OpenVPN PKI passphrase, in the `.ovpn` file?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used `pivpn add nopass`, and created a `.ovpn` file with no PKI password.